# eager loading multi level categories

Tags: laravel, categories, eager-loading

i have a categories table with parent_id to store categories and subcategories. this categories can be multi level which means a category can have subcategories and each subcategory can have subcategories and so on. and it is dynamic so the levels number in not limited. i defined a function in Category model with name as below:

```
public function childs()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Category::class, 'parent_id');
}
```

Now i want to eager load the categories with subcategories. the code

```
$cats = Category::with('childs')->get();
```

works greate but it gets just one level of subcategories and i want to eager load all levels. something like

```
$cats = Category:with('childs')->with('childs')... ->get();
```

is there any way to do that? to get all category levels?
if there isn't, how to get all levels of subcategories in one collection without eager loading?

Comment: https://github.com/lazychaser/laravel-nestedset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this to load all subcategories

```
class Category extends Model
{
    public function children()
    {
        return $this->hasMany($this, 'parent_id');
    }

    public function childrenTree()
    {
        return $this->children()->with('childrenTree');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just call your relation withing your relation. I mean recursively.
Try this code:

```
class Category extends Model
{
   public function subCategory()
   {
      return $this->hasMany(Category::class, 'parent_id')->with('subCategory');
    }
}
```